# data model in Power BI with multiple tables each has an FK

Tags: powerbi

Assume I have the following tables:

```
 Table 1:
 Prj_id, name
 1     , prj1
 2     , prj2
 3     , prj3


Table 2
prj_id, cost, year
1     ,100  ,1999
1     ,200  ,2000
1     ,300  ,3000
2     ,150  ,1998


Table 3
Prj_id, manager
1     , xxx
1     , yyy
2     , xxx
3     , zzz
```

Now my question is:

Shall I connect all tables together in the model (relation tab) of BI, if I have all the attributes as filters on the page

i.e.

```
 Table 1 to 2 ->Both direction
 Table 1 to 3 ->Both direction
 Table 2 to 3 ->Both direction
```

or shall I need to only join tables as follows:

```
  Table 1 to 2->Both direction
  Table 1 to 3->Both direction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That highly depends on what your final goal is.

However I would create a relationship between this tables. As I looks, these data coming from a database with a good structure, so why joining every together again.

Comment: "these data coming from a database with a good structure, so why joining every together again",  The reason I guess is that I am "direct query" the data, so the relations are not imported automatically, the other reason is that I need to provde some results to user which utilizes all the tables, e.g. total cost of project_name per manager. However, As your answer suggests I need to connect all the three tables together like a triangle, right?

Comment: Jep, you can do that in the relationship tab. Connect the table by their key, foreign keys. If you do so, you can put a table into Power BI and drag some fields into it, you can see that the data displayed in the table comes from all 3 tables or not (depending what fields you put into the table).